# An Innoscript won't start after having been downloaded from a server

Tags: windows

I have an Inncoscript that works fine when I start it from my PC harddrive. But when it is downloaded from a server by a web site, it gives the following error message: "This app can't run on your PC." The strange thing is that it has worked before, some months ago. I have not registered the program Innoscript is supposed to launch at Microsoft yet, because it costs a lot of money and because it still is in the testing phase. I get warnings and am asked if I really want to run the Innoscript program. After clicking yes, the error message occur. The actual program to be launced is made in C by Visual Studio, and I am using Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-fix-the-this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-error-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The path had been changed.